# Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab

Tags: git, ssh, authorized-keys

I set up a git server and want now to push initially my repo from the client.
I used `git push origin master` and get this error message:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab
```

I don't know what's wrong. I don't know what "Unab" is. I tried to resize the shell but it is still "Unab".
I cannot find a solution for this error message.

I setup the server with "authorized_keys" and SSH. (I can connect to it, using SSH.)

It seems to be a git problem?

BTW: The server is set up in a Windows 7 VM

Comment: Had similar issue with "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: This", my error message was "This account is currently not available."

Comment: FWIW: I sometimes get a similar error at the very end of a git deploy to my Heroku app, but it seems to have no effect (the deploy succeeds).

Answer (score 140, accepted):

This error message is a bit obtuse, but what it's actually trying to tell you is that the remote server didn't reply with a proper git response.  Ultimately, there was a problem on the server running the `git-receive-pack` process.

In the Git protocol, the first four bytes should be the line length.  Instead, they were the characters `Unab`...  which is probably the beginning an error message of some kind.  (ie, it's probably "`Unable to...`" do something).

What happens when you run `ssh <host> git-receive-pack <path-to-git-repository>`?  You should see the error message that your git client is barfing on and you may be able to correct it.

Comment: That, and `ssh <host> /bin/true` shouldn't output anything.

Comment: Okay, the output from git-receive-pack is: "Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process." Iam able to connect with ssh via putty or other ssh-clients (git's ssh). but i cant doing git-stuff...

Comment: i found the problem. ssh cant access the git methods. i have to reference to the git bash-functions. i think i have to edit the .bashc file in the ssh-server folder, but my attempts didnot work...

Comment: I had this same issue and the cause was an 'echo ".bashrc"' in my .bashrc, so instead of "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab" I was seeing "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: .bas".

Comment: Right, that was my problem too: my `.bashrc` at the machine that hosted the Git repository I was trying to pull from had a line that produced an echo to the standard output. (That is, I was the owner of the repository on the remote machine, so it was my `.bashrc` that caused the problem.) I used the trick given by user ruslo in another answer, namely redirecting the output of that command from stdout to stderr (`some_command 1>&2`). After that, `git pull` worked again.

Comment: git-receive-pack: "This service allows sftp connections only.", please help. nvm, found answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163295/cloning-a-git-repository-over-sftp

Comment: With the above command, the output just hangs.  It lists all my branches, one per line, and then on the final printed line I get the output `0000`  and the cursor immediately after as if another line were to be written out but never completes.

Comment: Any feedback you generate in say git hooks must go to stderr and not to stdout which is reserved to the git protocol.

Comment: While this answer is interesting, it provides little to none real solutions for the problem.

Comment: You're not wrong, @Dariusz.  But without knowing what the error message _is_, I couldn't possibly tell you how to correct it.  Run the `ssh` command I indicated, read the error message, and then you can go from there.

Comment: @demongolem how'd you solve that? I see 0000 as well.

Comment: I hate to bump a seven year old issue, but I get the same 0000 issue with git-receive-pack. It hangs there until I press return four times, at which point it reports the same protocol error and quits.

Comment: Those comments saved my day. Anything printed (echo-ed or similar) in your .bashrc can messed up the git command!

Comment: For me the issue was simply that my SSH key was not added on the server (just a normal auth issue). The error message could have been a bit better :)

Comment: What exactly replaces <host>? I assume <host> was just the URL to the git repository but that didn't seem to work. Could someone paste an example of this command filled in with a realistic looking input for host and path-to-git

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Just parse the URL or SCP path.  If you're cloning `git@github.com:/user/repo.git` then host is `github.com` and the path is `user/repo.git`.  So run `ssh github.com git-receive-pack /user/repo.git`.

Comment: similar error, ending in "This": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314298/git-push-results-in-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-this

Comment: I get with git clone: `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: logi`. `ssh 192.168.178.36 git-receive-pack /gt_sr/doks.git` leads to (after 4 times return): `008d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{} report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta agent=git/2.11.0
0000
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:`. The bad line length character changed to empty. I will now try to run the key agent of putty pageant. Before the protocol error git clone stopped at the cache question. I then started putty and it saved the key in the putty cache.

Comment: In my case, the 4 letters were the first 4 letters of my username. The problem was that I started to work with another machine, and I created a new .ssh credentials, but the server has stored the old credentials. The solution was to copy the C/Users/my.user/.shh files from the old machine to the new machine, and everything started to work!

Comment: From what I understand it's the server trying to start the interactive login process,which confuses git. What I don't understand is that it used to work before but stopped working after upgrading git and its GUI clients. The fix seems to be to avoid passwords and use key based auth.

Answer (score 76):

I had similar issue, but the exact error message was:

> fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Usin

This is in Windows, with `GIT_SSH` set to the path of `plink.exe` of PuTTY.

Possible problems and solutions:

- Make sure the path to `plink.exe` is correct. Unix style path works fine too, for example `/c/work/tools/PuTTY/plink.exe`
- Make sure the key agent of PuTTY (`pageant.exe`) is running
- Make sure the key agent contains a valid key to access the server

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows and turned out to be the same root cause for the opposite reason. I was trying to use Cygwin (and the embedded Git SSH) but GIT_SSH was set to C:\...\plink.exe which causing a conflict. Once I removed this everything worked fine.

Comment: Removing GIT_SSH entry from the environment variables did the trick for me

Comment: Similar error after upgrading GitExt had to restart pageant and reimport .ppk key file.

Comment: I simply forgot to load the private key in pageant what ended in `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@`. What a misleading error message.

Comment: In my case (Windows 10) pageant was not running. Once I started it up and added the private key to it, this Just Worked.

Comment: @Ludwig Many thanks - was exactly that for me as well. I'd updated the remote in GitExtensions but forgotten to associate my key file with the remote, and got that message.

Comment: If ssh works passwordless (key auth), do I still need pageant? Is pageant like a bridge for git and ssh?

Comment: Similar: ```fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: | Pa.```  Pageant needed a restart.  A below entry indicated rebooting windows and restarting Pageant.  I suspect that was overkill and restarting Pageant was all that was necessary (but I've been wrong before)

Answer (score 40):

> For GitExtension users:

I faced the same issue after upgrading git to 2.19.0

> Solution:

Tools > Settings > Git Extensions > SSH

Select [**OpenSSH**] instead of [***PuTTY***]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I've done, when you get the error `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@`. Make sure that the SSH key is generated and added to *GitLab*. Perhaps the restart of *Git Extensions* was necessary.

Comment: A similar error occurred with SoureTree, the solution is the same. Under Tools > Options > General > SSH Client -> Set to OpenSSH instead of PuTTY / Plink

Answer (score 33):

I had the same kind of problem after installing GIT on Windows. At first it worked; then, a day later (after a PC reboot), it didn't anymore, and I got this:

```
$ git pull
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@
```

The problem was that after the reboot, the automatically started Putty "pageant.exe" didn't have the private key active anymore. When you add a key in pageant, it's not a persistent setting by default. I just had to add the key again, and it worked fine. So, for that case, it's necessary to make pagenant load the key automatically, as discussed here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pageant-to-streamline-ssh-key-authentication-with-putty

Comment: For me the situation was that in Visual studio I got error: "Git failed with a fatal error.
protocol error: bad line length character: gitu" every time Windows got restarted. The pageant process was not started at all. I needed to use e.g. TortoiseGit that solved this on background and then GIT worked in Visual studio like a charm.

Comment: This was the correct answer in my case. This has happened to me me several times. Putty will load the key properly and everything works fine for weeks or months. Then randomly one day the authentication agent starts, but doesn't load the key and I get that generic error message and go down a rabbit hole trying to figure out what went wrong. This is the first thing to check if you're on Windows. Switching to OpenSSH has worked to allow the connection through, but I've had problems configuring that, so I don't want to rely on it.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe you have a statement in the server's .bashrc that produces output. I, for example had this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32
```

In this case the output from the rvm use will be (wrongly) interpreted as coming from git. So replace it by:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails32 > /dev/null
```

Comment: In my (windows 10) case, the problem was the output of some docker related commands at my cmd startup init.cmd script (which I created by those instructions: stackoverflow.com/questions/17404165/…). but it's the same principal. thank you!

Comment: This was the case for me. I had a 'banner' command in my .bashrc. Commenting it out fixed the issue. Thank you :).

Answer (score 15):

After loading the SSH private key in Git Extensions, this issue gets resolved.

Comment: for me - adding ssh private key to pageant

Comment: My pageant instance died silently. After starting it again the error went away.

Comment: This happened to me after a push got interrupted and the previously setup key data seemed to be corrupted. This fix worked for that.

Answer (score 11):

You can redirect any output from `.bashrc` to `stderr`:

```
# inside .bashrc
echo 'some error/warning/remind message' 1>&2
```

git will ignore this symbols

Comment: That did it for me. I had a statement `rvm use 2.0.0-p353` in my `.bashrc`, which must have confused `git pull`. After appending `1>&2` and trying again, `git pull` worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem on Windows using Git Bash. I kept getting this error when trying to do a git clone. The repository was on a Linux box with GitLab installed.

```
git clone git@servername:path/to/repo
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@
```

I made sure the ssh key was generated. The public key was added on GitLab. The ssh-agent was running and the generated key was added ([github link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)).

I ran out of options and then finally tried closing Git Bash and opening it again by right clicking 'Run as Administrator'. Worked after that.

Comment: I see the same thing (Windows 10 64-bit) but running as administrator doesn't fix it.

Comment: I have a hunch about what causes this.  If you don't have the ssh keypair set up (or it is not readable for some reason) then ssh prompts for a password.  On Windows there isn't a clear distinction between standard output and console output, so the password prompt goes to stdout: "git@whatever's password:".  This is seen by git as corrupted protocol output.

Comment: @EdAvis Thanks! I had the same problem and after reading your comment I double checked my key agent (which is usually run at startup on my machine). It turned out that it was not running for some reason ...

Answer (score 6):

For me it was becuase I recently added

```
RequestTTY force
```

into .ssh/config

commenting this out allowed it to work

Comment: And in my case I added a `LocalCommand` config to echo something

Answer (score 5):

This might help someone. When I was trying to clone a project from an EC2 instance, I was getting the below error:

```
Cloning into 'repo1'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: logi
```

The resolution for me includes the below steps:

1. Ensure SSH key (public) is added/updated in the EC2 instance.
2. Ensure authentication agent (in my case its Pageant=Putty Authentication Agent) is running and the corresponding private key is loaded.
3. Use the EC2 SSH key ID for the public key for git clone. Example:

   git clone ssh://{SSH Key ID}@someaccount.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repo1

Comment: Note: This is because you're using plink, and if you do `plink <server_name> ls` then the first thing plink prints to stdout is `login as`, which git appears to be trying to interpret as something important.

A quick fix is to simply `unset GIT_SSH` and `unset SVN_SSH`.

More info [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/30691481-username-required-when-cloning-with-plink)

Comment: @Pod you are right, on windows these commands should help: `set GIT_SSH=` and `set SVN_SSH=`

Comment: I had the same issue with TFS. After adding the key id everything works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my case after fetch it was written: `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Pass`. Also after push I got: `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@
Done`.

After reboot of Windows I had to start "PuTTY agent" (pageant.exe) again and add a private key that disappeared from a list of keys.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Putty. Then make sure to have Pageant running and your private key is loaded in Pageant (mouse right-click on Pageant icon on the Taskbar and click "View keys" on the menu that pops up).

Otherwise when you do in cmd.exe :

`git clone ssh://name@host:/path/to/git/repo.git`

you get this message "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:"

Comment: I came to the same conclusion on a Windows 10 PC with Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Do *not* omit `username@` in your remote URLs when on Windows.

On Linux and on Windows with the default ssh, you can omit the username from remote URLs, like so:

```
git clone server-name:/srv/git/repo-name
```

Because ssh's default behavior is to just use whatever username you're currently logged in with.  If you're on Windows and have set up git to use `plink.exe` so that you can use the key loaded in your `pageant`, then this will not work, because `plink` does not have this same automatic username behavior, resulting in those cryptic error messages, because it will prompt for the username:

```
$ plink server-name
login as: _
```

Versus:

```
$ plink username@server-name
...logs you in...
```

If you already cloned a repository somehow you can fix the remotes in your `.git/config` by adding the `username@` to the remote URL.

Comment: Adding username to remote by `git remote set-url origin myusername@...` helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Check your startup files on the account used to connect to the remote machine for "echo" statements. For the Bash shell these would be your .bashrc and .bash_profile etc. Edward Thomson is correct in his answer but a specific issue that I have experienced is when there is some boiler-plate printout upon login to a server via ssh. Git will get the first four bytes of that boiler-plate and raise this error. Now in this specific case I'm going to guess that "Unab" is actually the work "Unable..." which probably indicates that there is something else wrong on the Git host.

Answer (score 2):

i also encounter that error once in a while, but when it does, it means that my branch is not up-to-date so i have to do `git pull origin <current_branch>`

Answer (score 2):

FYI I got this same error message after I upgraded a CentOS6 container to CentOS7 -- some git operations started failing when building the container, e.g.

```
# git remote show origin
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Inva
```

Running ssh gave me an error I could search on:

```
# ssh git@bitbucket.org
Invalid clock_id for clock_gettime: 7
```

That led me to https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime/issues/63 where I realized I had forgotten I had a `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/faketime/libfaketime.so.1` in a parent Dockerfile. Commenting that out fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was 32-bit Putty and pageant.exe - it can't communicate with 64-bit TortoisePlink.exe. Replacing 32-bit Putty with a 64-bit version solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error `"fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: shmi"`
Where the `shmi` is user name in my case.
I switched SSH from PuTTY to OpenSSH in `"Git Extensions->Settings->SSH"`.
It helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as Christer Fernstrom. In my case it was a message I had put in my .bashrc that reminds me do do a backup when I haven't done one in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

The following may help someone:
When trying to clone a project I have on my AWS EC2 instance I was getting the following error:

```
Cloning into 'AWSbareRepo'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Plea
```

This was caused by trying to ssh as root instead of EC2-USER.
if you actually ssh without doing a git clone... you will see the error msg in something along the lines of "Please login with ec2-user"
Once I did a git clone as a ec2-user it was good.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't prompt for password and fails with similar cryptic message "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: user" **if you don't have your private key authentication setup** as well.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server tells how to specify public key on the server. Basically add the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2

I had to struggle a bit on how to provide private key to the Git Bash on the windows machine. Dan McClain's answer in https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key/382801#382801 describes that. One addition to his answer, in my case the private key file was expected to be named id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 1):

For me adding the same host details into Putty with the private key (convert with puttygen) worked. Any git bash commands after that had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Had some similar issue but *git fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Cann* and I was not able getting rid of it until I got rid of all the `plink.exe` dependency (have installed the Putty via `choco` installer) but also removed the next line from the `.gitconfig` file `sshCommand = plink -batch`.

Comment: I had this error.  I found that I could no longer run PuTTY.  Uninstalled and re-installed PuTTY (via Chocolatey) and it fixed my Git error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Shell access is allowed on the server.

Comment: mine was "Hi g". turns out that i followed some Security Setup website and now my git login says "Hi git! You've successfully authenticated, but I do not provide interactive shell access.". guess ill have to remove that....

Answer (score 0):

The error transformed in:
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: fata

after adding the location of git-upload-pack to the system path.

The problem seem to be an apostrophe added around the repository name: Looking with a tool like Process Monitor (from sys internals), that were added by the git client. It seems to be a git specific windows problem.

I tried the same command line in the prompt of the server: the full error was "fatal: not a given repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

In conclusion, to me it seems like a software bug. Be advised that I am not a git expert, it is first time I use git, i come from subversion and perforce.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this as well.

```
Counting objects: 85, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Writing objects: 100% (38/38), 3.38 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 38 (delta 33), reused 0 (delta 0)
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Remo
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
```

I don't know the gitty details about what went wrong, but in our case what triggered it was that the disk on the server was full.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a security access on your machine, are you running Pageant (which is a putty agent)?

Answer (score 0):

you can always have http link to your git project. You can use that instead of ssh link. This is just an option you have

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had this same issue (Windows 7). Try to get repo by password.
I use Git Bash + Plink (environment variable GIT_SSH) + Pageant.
Deleting GIT_SSH (temporary) helps me. I don't know why I can't use login by pass and login with RSA at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here, but hope it will help someone. If its a protocol error, it has to do something with your local git not able to communicate to the remote git. This can happen if you cloned the repo via ssh and sometime later, you lost the keys to the repo or your ssh agent cannot find those keys anymore.

Solution

1. Generate a new key and add it your git repo or configure your ssh agent to load the keys if you still have the keys with you & not with someone else ;)
2. Another quick fix is to go to your `.git` directory and edit the `config` file's `[remote "origin"] url` from `git` to `http` so that ssh keys are not needed to push and it will revert to asking your username and password.

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
   url = git@gitlab.*****.com:****/****.git
   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   ```

Change to

```
    [remote "origin"]
    url = http://gitlab.*****.com/****/****.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ssh exectuable from builtin to nativ under settings/version control/git did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I did git pull

git pull fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: <htm fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

I changed my remote url HTTP to SSH, and it worked for me.

**git remote set-url origin** "**HTTP**" to "**SSH**"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue is caused by a modified `/bin/ssh`.
I work on a server with other people and the default `/bin/ssh` is somehow modified,
it outputs unintended logs when starting.
I restore the `/bin/ssh` to the correct executable and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a rather old thread but when I had a very similar error message, I only got hints from this posts to investigate around SSH. I forgot that I put up an sshrc with an "echo" in it to test. So if you are running some form of UNIX, and get this error, then try looking into the following files:

- `/etc/sshrc`: runs for any user login
- `~/.ssh/rc`: runs for a specific user login

If these scripts have stdout then I think it can confuse the SSH key exchange process. At least it did it for me. Removing the echoes lines fixed my issue.