# Cloning a Git repository over SFTP

Tags: git, ssh, sftp

I get a fatal error every time I try to clone my Git repository:

I run this:

```
$ git clone sftp://foo@bar.ca/git/foobar.git
```

and I get this:

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'sftp'
```

I'm trying to clone from one server to another, both of which use SSH authentication.

Is there something I need to install to enable this SFTP remote helper?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer!

Comment: I don't think `git` directly supports sftp: you should use an `ssh://` URL.

Comment: What happens when you do `git clone foo@bar.ca/git/foobar.git`?

Comment: Im betting he will get an error from not specifying a protocol. Git supports ftps is which is different. Im guessing the reason it doesnt support sftp is because if you had ssh set up then you would not need sftp here

Comment: Thanks Borealid. You seem to be right.

Comment: sftp seems to be way faster than ftp, and sometimes on a shared hosting you can install git to your home directory and setup a $PATH if you log on over SSH, but not for the case when you execute a command over ssh (which is the way git works with ssh remote repos). So, SFTP is the option to choose in these cases.

Answer (score 8):

To make *jdi*'s comment from above more explicit: There is no sftp remote helper in Git. [Available remote helpers](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote-helpers.html) include git-remote-**ftps**, but **ftps** ([FTP over SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS)) and **sftp** ([SSH File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)) are [fundamentally different protocols](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-ftps-and-sftp/). That said, using ftps to clone a Git repository is rather uncommon, you probably want to use ssh instead.