# fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Plea

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab)

I am trying to configure a git server on an Amazon EC2 instance and I keep getting this error.

Everything is all set up properly - I have my ssh keys valid and I can log into the remote server however git spews out this error all the time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab

Comment: Yes; his own issue was with ssh access - my server is fine and I can ssh into it.

Comment: Ok.  Looks like the title has been cut off... Can you post the full message?

Comment: This is exactly what I get:
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Plea

Comment: Okay, you can ssh into it, but what happens when you run `ssh <host> git-receive-pack <path-to-git-repository>`?  Might you get an error message that starts with the word "Please"...?