# Git Error: bad line length character: Sysl

Tags: git, heroku, git-push, git-pull

Working on a project with some guys, we are all pretty new to using git, and we just came across an error allowing none of us to perform a pull/push on our repo. (we are also using heroku)

"
Fetching repositoryfatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Sysl
"

I was wondering if anyone else is familiar with this error? Every other search I find is related to "bad line length character: Unab" and related to changing our bash_profiles? But bash_profile would be related to a error that is local, and not server side correct?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do any of you guys use a Windows machine?

Comment: What I see from a quick search is that it *is* about the files on the server, on a server that doesn't just run git, but also allows users to log in (so it's about the .bash_profile on the server). Either way, it's a truncated error message, and you should be able to see the full message by taking git out of it and attempting to log in directly. That is, despite getting a different error message, the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8170436/743382) should help you too in figuring out what it going on.

Comment: Half of our team is on mac and half on windows.

hvd- we read through the link you posted, it mentions to run the following command to figure out which file is causing the issues:

ssh <host> git-receive-pack <path-to-git-repository>

for host, does it mean the host URL, is there a command to figure out the correct host URL? we've been just using the heroku git for our git URL

Comment: Unless heroku does things differently from how Git normally works, you can check the Git configuration file (`.git/config` in your local repository). You will probably see a `url = git://somehost/path/project.git` line in a `remote` section. `somehost` is the host.