# Git push failed: can not push specific file to remote repo

Tags: git, git-push

I have had a git server (git 1.7.1 on CentOS 6.5) running normally for a year,
and `git clone`/`pull`/`push` via https worked like a charm.
But today, when I try to push [this file](http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js) to my server, it fails with the following error message:

```
Counting objects: 17, done.  
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 11.33 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.  
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)  
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: < HTM    
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (13370 ms @ 2014/8/28 PM 01:54:39)
```

Now my local repo seems broken; I cannot push any file to my server.
I tried to run `git rm docs.min.js` but it still fails to push any file.
If I clone this repo to another working directory, though, I can push files normally.

I have tried several git clients including TortoiseGit on Windows 7, git on CentOS 6, git on Mac OSX 10.8, but all have the same problem.

Google searching indicates it is a server side problem, but my git server seems to be working fine. All other files, repositories can `git clone`/`pull`/`push`.

Running `git-receive-pack` gets the following result:

```
00729cb8e722e189b90b7962bf94b91a8cefd8a819da refs/heads/master report-status delete-refs side-band-64k ofs-delta
003e9cb8e722e189b90b7962bf94b91a8cefd8a819da refs/tags/latest
003cbd3510b705ebc9def3afcac0a9bb59ba81a0960d refs/tags/prod
003be9c1bff213332f15892eb1a9c790c9737599b3fa refs/tags/v30
003b0411cb4c7be5f3d3bc4c80a70f10417bd34daed0 refs/tags/v31
003b6070e4869ccce82d0bc778821d748145a0575c2b refs/tags/v32
003b0d62d04331cd3067d93e1003ae8de56cee6601c1 refs/tags/v33
003bb40d0720f0bca2791c8b83b191e9faa673f25980 refs/tags/v34
003bab3cc6a4de19771625a9c30f9f75670745f61a7d refs/tags/v35
003b1f2e45a887653656e36f618839032265aae97989 refs/tags/v36
003b86423373fbecd056d63850e46bca22271bd73e09 refs/tags/v37
003bbd3510b705ebc9def3afcac0a9bb59ba81a0960d refs/tags/v38
003b9cb8e722e189b90b7962bf94b91a8cefd8a819da refs/tags/v39
0000
```

It hangs on `0000`, and no error messages are shown.

Any idea?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab

So the problem is not with the file, it's with the repository sending bad protocol messages.

Comment: @Malt According to the related post, I run `git-receive-pack` and post the result above. But I still have no idea of what happens. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What do you use on the server side? The protocol error looks like the beginning of HTML.

Comment: musiKk is right, "<HTM" does look like the start of an HTML response. Being a networking guy (rather than a big git expert), I'd try capturing this transaction using wireshark or a similar packet sniffer. See what's being sent on the line. It's probably an error page from the server...

Comment: @musiKk I use git + gitolite + nginx on CentOS. Do you mean this?

Comment: @yhan Yes. Do you access gitolite over SSH as it should be or somehow over HTTP? You can verify this with `git remote -v`.

Comment: @musiKk I use https, both for fetch and push.

Comment: @yhan Hm, maybe it really is some HTML that gets sent erroneously. But that doesn't explain why it's only that file. Maybe your repository is corrupted? What does `git fsck` say?

Comment: @yhan could you try capturing your attempted `git push` using wireshark? The HTML might provide some clues to what went wrong.

Comment: @Malt Won't do much good if it's HTTPS.

Comment: @musiKk true, I missed that part.

Comment: @musiKk `git fsck` shows no error (actually, no message at all).   @Malt packet sniffer doesn't work, because I use https...

Comment: @yhan Only thing I can think of now is looking at the log files of gitolite and nginx, probably configuring finer log levels.

Comment: @musiKk I have checked nginx debug log and gitolite log, but no useful clues are found. Anyways, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: This problem disappears, but I don't know why. :( I didn't modify any configurations. I can push the file normally now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to gitolite over ssh you can verify with `git-remote -v`; and, if you don't, use http use the `git fsck` command.