# git on Windows: fatal: protocol error: bad line character: @-

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell, atlassian-sourcetree

I was using SourceTree + Git on Windows without any problem. I was able to use git commands from command (terminal/BASH). I prefer to use terminal for git push/pull etc. Unfortunately, after reinstallation of my machine (server/git are the same), I'm getting this painful error.

On a new machine, I installed Git 1.9.5 (Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe) and configured to use BASH only and plink with proper SSH key file.

I can do `git log` on my repository, but `git pull` or `git push` gives this error:

```
me@NEW-MACHINE /c/Workspace/project (master)
$ git pull
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:
@-

ERROR: Problem parsing the command line arguments.
```

Of course, I searched many articles related to "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character". But, couldn't find any clue.

Interestingly, on SourceTree, I can do `git pull` or `push` successfully. I'm only getting this error in BASH terminal. Note that SourceTree doesn't use embedded git.

Here are my investigations so far:

- I installed an older version of git (1.8.x), still getting error.
- Moved .bashrc, but no good.
- Obviously, not a problem of SourceTree as SourceTree doesn't use embedded Git.
- The server is in Github (enterprise, private).
- I have no problem using any git commands on my Linux with the same git repository/server.

My clue is `<newline>@-<newline>` from the error message. It is more like a problem of Windows/BASH-specific problem. I can't figure it out what causes "@-".

**Edit**: I tried suggestions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab), but didn't solve my problem. The git server is `github.mycompany.com`, which doesn't allow any `ssh` connection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab)

Comment: I tried the answers in that thread, but didn't work. Edited question.

Comment: What connection method are you using to that server? http(s)?

Comment: Probably https. It is an enterprise Github. The interface is pretty much the same with public Github.

Comment: Is that issue visible with other users?

Comment: And if you are using https, then ssh key doesn't matter.

Comment: Don't "probably" your answer. Check your git configuration for that remote. What does it say?

Comment: What (exactly) is the [complete] command you are using for `git pull`?  What is the result of `git remote -v`?`  I **strongly** suspect the `@` is in [one of] your git remotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent the bash-ssh issue entirely by:

- launching a DOS shell with [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) (packaged within your Git for Windows msysgit distribution)
- using git clone to make a new clone using the proper https url of your remote repo.

That is:

```
git clone https://<yourAccount>@github.mycompany.com/<yourAccount>/<yourRepo>
```

Since you will be using in this case the https protocol, there won't be any shell session during a git pull (as opposed to the ssh protocol: see [The Smart Protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol)), and you shouldn't see any extra message like `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for git in windows.
Load your public/private key by Pageant App (Putty Authentication Agent).
[add private/public key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJCZI.png).