# Git fails with "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Pass"

Tags: git, ssh

All git commands requiring access to the remote repository fail with the error message:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Pass
```

They used to work a few days ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that my ssh key agent (Pageant) wasn't running.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similarly issue while setting up aws codecommit, I need to add the .ppk to pageant.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Add private key

#### 2. Start Pageant.exe