# TFS/Git fatal:* Closing connection 1 protocol error: bad line length character: <htm fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: windows, git, tfs

When doing a git pull, I receive this error (git push still works fine).

Our setup is windows client using git bash and windows authentication to a windows tfs server. This is not a new repository, we have been using it for close to a year.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175315/4627632) stackoverflow post seems to point towards how to see what our problem is, but I need a http equivalent, since we do not authenticate or connect over ssh.

I have run `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git pull`
with the output part that breaks being:

```
GET /tfs/company/_git/product/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1     
Host: server:8080 
Authorization: HASH_TO_AUTH 
User-Agent: git/2.13.3.windows.1 
Accept: */* 
Accept-Encoding: gzip Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Cache-Control: private 
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement 
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 
< X-TFS-ProcessId: 95bbb597-666c-44c8-8599-32c2e6156999 
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN 
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 
< Persistent-Auth: true 
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
< P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT" 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
< Date: Tue, 29 Aug 2017 07:28:44 GMT 
< Content-Length: 3006 
<
* Connection #1 to host server left intact 09:28:45.176632 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager store' 09:28:45.198649 git.c:547               trace: exec: 'git-credential-manager' 'store' 09:28:45.198649 run-command.c:626     trace: run_command: 'git-credential-manager' 'store' 09:28:45.394115 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'rev-list' '--objects' '--stdin' '--not' '--all' '--quiet' 09:28:45.418132 run-command.c:626  trace: run_command: 'fetch-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--stdin' '--lock-pack' '--include-tag' '--thin' 'http://server:8080/tfs/company/_git/product/' 09:28:45.426138 git.c:322               trace: built-in: git 'fetch-pack' '--stateless-rpc' '--stdin' '--lock-pack' '--include-tag' '--thin' 'http://server:8080/tfs/company/_git/product/'
* Couldn't find host server in the _netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host server: 0x2fc6fb0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#1) with host server
* Connected to server (10.134.15.175) port 8080 (#1)
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'name@company.com'
> POST /tfs/company/_git/product/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1 
Host: server:8080 
User-Agent: git/2.13.3.windows.1 
Accept-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request 
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
Content-Length: 674

* upload completely sent off: 674 out of 674 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body 
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK 
< Connection: close 
< Content-Type: text/html 
< 
fatal:* Closing connection 1 protocol error: bad line length character: <htm 
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: The error message "<htm" is truncated, can you install Fiddler on the machine and set Git proxy to Fiddler to check if you can get the detailed message responded from server?

Comment: When using Fiddler as proxy I do not see any response starting with <html, only what seems like normal responses. Did discover that issue is only occurring through our VPN, on site there no issue. When off-site will debug further. Is there any reason that I won't see some of the responses via Fiddler?

Comment: Is there any response contains the string "<html"?

Comment: There isn't, I will edit my post with the responses I pickup from Fiddler tonight/tomorrow