# jetBrains intelliJ IDEA: protocol error: bad line length character: Acti

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Toast `protocol error: bad line length character: Acti` while using git plugin of jetBrains IDE.

This issue just happened in JetBrains IDE, I got not error while use `git bash` to clone, push, pull...  so it confused me and I don't know what to do with it.

I'm googling and googling, but coming up empty so far.
So here I am, hoping someone else can guide me through this.

[image: the screenshot of this issue]

@VonC Oh, thx guy. I found the way to resolve it. The key is SSH executable in jetbrains IDE configuration. I changed the SSH executable Built-in to Native, then the SSH connection established.

Comment: Are you using an SSH URL? (git@xxx:user/repo)

Comment: @VonC yep, I'm using SSH protocol. And SSH Key is fine. 
Everything is good in git shell, but error occurred while I use jetbrains git plugin.

Comment: Is your Git (in IntelliJ) configured to use PUTTY? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913460/6309)

Comment: @VonC Oh, thx guy. I found the way to resolve it. The key is SSH executable in jetbrains IDE configuration. I changed the SSH executable Built-in to Native, then the SSH connection established.

Comment: @VonC Thx again, I' m new of stackOverFlow and not good at English. IDK if I use the right way to accept ur answer. if i‘m wrong. talk me how to do. thank you.

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you and welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP confirms it is an IntelliJ SSH configuration issue.

See "[Using Git integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html)":

> If your remote uses the SSH protocol, in addition to configuring a password policy, you can choose whether you want to use a native or a built-in SSH executable.
>   To do this, in the `Settings/Preferences` dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), select `Version Control | Git` on the left.
>   From the SSH executable drop-down list, select one of the following options:
>
> - **Built-in**: all authorization is performed on the IDE side.
>     If login and password are used for authentication, authorization is performed in accordance with the selected password policy.
>     If an SSH key without a passphrase is used for authentication, IntelliJ IDEA will access the `~/.ssh/config` file and get the key from there.
>     If authentication requires an SSH key with a passphrase, Git looks for it in the credential helper, and, if no credential helper is found, it returns a prompt to the IDE. If you have configured a password policy, IntelliJ IDEA looks for credentials in the passwords database. If there is no passwords database, it displays a prompt and you have to enter SSH key and a passphrase.
> - **Native**: all authorization is performed on Git side. No prompt will be displayed, so choose this authorization type if you are using SSH without a passphrase, or the passphrase is saved in a credentials helper, or there is an SSH agent.

Using Git authorization is in this instance the right setting.