# fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: <htm

Tags: git, github

I've been getting this error everytime I try to push to git. Can someone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it ? Thank you.

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: <htm
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab)

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing to a remote server with an ssh URL, double-check the `.profile` or `.bashrc` of the remote user.

If that resource file is echoing anything, that would be enough to trigger that protocol error.

Alternatively, if you can (if the remote server supports it), switch to https:

```
git remote set-url origin https://url/remote/repo
```