# Git HTTP error 'fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: '

Tags: c, git, http, protocols, git-http-backend

I'm currently trying to create a simple Git HTTP Server in C without an already existing Web server. Currently the only thing I do is creating a server socket and executing the git-http-backend CGI script with the Environment Variables from the Client Request. The Pull Request already works, but only for empty repositories. When I'm trying to clone a repository with content, I'm getting this Error on the client side:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:
```

Here is the communication log between client and server:

```
C: GET /test.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
C: Host: localhost:9000
C: User-Agent: git/2.20.1
C: Accept: */*
C: Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
C: Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
C: Pragma: no-cache
C:

S: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
S: Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
S: Pragma: no-cache
S: Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
S: Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
S: 
S: 001e# service=git-upload-pack
S: 000000fadd3fba560f4afe000e70464ac3a7a9991ad13eb0
S: HEAD003fdd3fba560f4afe000e70464ac3a7a9991ad13eb0 refs/heads/master
S: 0000
```

Just a little side note: HTTP/1.1 200 OK is added manually, the rest is from the CGI script. Also you can find my code [here](https://github.com/diedummheitinperson/sgs/blob/master/sgs.c).
 First I had the theory, that the content of of the server response has a false placement of the new lines (e.g. The HEAD should be a line higher), but turns out this is not really the case. So my Question is: Is there anything I could do? Editing this response to a good format is pretty complicated in C, especially with longer responses.

Comment: Verify your theory. Hard-code the complete response with what you think is correct and see what happens.

Comment: From your code: `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"` - this should be `\r\n` not `\n` according to the HTTP standard although most clients will ignore it. Similar all other line ends in the HTTP header and also the delimiter between header and body should be `\r\n` not `\n`.

Comment: OK, so I tried to change the response, but the error still appears.

Comment: And I fixed the HTTP status. Still no change.

Comment: This answer explain the error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175315/1023553
Your are not sending the "line length". You should see where in the http backend protocol it should be sent.

Comment: @NoDataFound Which line do you mean? Isn't it included with 00fa and 003f?

Comment: Sorry: I don't know GIT protocol but I am still interested by the question; I, however, tried to help you.

Comment: @NoDataFound No problem. I've already looked in the [git protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt), so I know a little bit of the background. However I still can't find the real error here, which is quite frustrating.

Comment: How the protocol defines an end of transaction? You are sending 10000 bytes, most of them garbage.

Comment: @user58697 According to the protocol, 0000 describes the end of the transaction. However, I do not think it's the size of the buffer. I only made it high, so that large repositories can also be sent. Anyway, in the future, I'm going to adjust the buffer size dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please make sure you understand the security implications of handing in data controlled by an outside actor to a function like `popen`. The implementation you have right now is trivially exploitable by shell injection by adding shell special characters to the request line. Even by just using git with a specially crafted repository name your current code allows arbitrary commands to execute on the server. Try this for example:

```
git clone "$(echo -e 'http://localhost:9000/;echo\tunexpected\t>helloworld;cat\t/etc/passwd;exit;.git')"
```

This will create a file in the working directory of the server with the string "unexpected" in it and will send back the contents of `/etc/passwd` to the client (use wireshark to see it).

To avoid this, you need to make sure that you properly escape the input data so that no shell injection can happen. Ideally you would use mechanisms like `execve` that allow you to hand in the environment variables and possible command line arguments as buffers instead of producing possibly unsafe strings that are then parsed by a shell. Such a solution is of course a bit more involved as it means restructuring your program.

Then you are using an unsafe way to concatenate strings. `strcat` has no way to know how large the destination buffer is, it will therefore happily overwrite the stack past the buffer given enough input. This is a classic stack overflow that can then be exploited. Use safer alternatives like `strlcat` or better yet a proper string library.

Now on to your original problem:

The output you get from `git http-backend` is raw binary output, including null bytes. In the example response there would indeed be a null byte after the `HEAD` separating off the supported feature list. You can see that by running your command manually and piping it to something like `xxd` or dumping it to a file and looking at it with a hex editor.

In the loop where you read from the pipe and then concatenate the output into your response buffer, you truncate the data because `strcat` operates on C strings that are terminated by a null byte. The rest of the `HEAD` line and the null byte itself never make it to the response, breaking the git protocol.

You can use `fread` to read raw data from the pipe directly into the buffer. Then you would need to copy that buffer to the response buffer with a function that doesn't stop at a null byte, like `memcpy`. For this to work you also need to keep track of the bytes already read and how much space still remains in the response buffer.

Alternatively, since you do not actually do any processing on the final response buffer, you could also directly send the data you read from the pipe to the client socket. This way you don't need to worry about the response buffer size and keeping track of the offset and remaining space. Here is a version that works for the initial request `git` does:

```
        char response[10000] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
        send(client_socket, response, strlen(response), 0);
        while (!feof(g)) {
            size_t bytes_read = fread(response, 1, sizeof(response), g);
            if (bytes_read == 0)
                break;

            send(client_socket, response, bytes_read, 0);
        }
```

The subsequent POST request then fails.