# Git push branch error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: logg

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push my changes to bitbucket and suddenly facing this issue of error when pushing to remote from any branch or even from any repo.

Not sure what this is about. Wondering if someone has come across this error or provide any help.

Please note, I'm able to pull/ clone any branch  or repo.

Please see the error I get below

fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: logg

Thanks

Expecting the local commits to be pushed to remote without any issue.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab

Comment: Had the exact same error. Couldn't find any info on atlasian support. Solved by moving my project over to gitlab and changing the remote origin host then push worked.