# git push not working for gitlab (mingw) -- what is the issue if ssh works?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have a windows PC trying to connect to gitlab via ssh. I have tested that the ssh connection works fine:

```
user MINGW32 /z/www/project (master)
$ ssh -T git@gitlab.foo.com
Welcome to GitLab, @user!
```

But pushing doesn't work:

```
user MINGW32 /z/www/project (master)
$ git push origin master
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
FATAL ERROR: Server sent disconnect message
type 2 (protocol error):
"Too many authentication failures"
```

This is the origin set previously:

```
$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.foo.com:my-project/project.git
$ git remote --verbose: 
origin  git@gitlab.foo.com:my-project/project.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.foo.com:my-project/project.git (push)
```

The errors looks like it's trying many keys and eventually failing, but I don't understand how ssh works then fine. Also in my .ssh folder i only have 1 key.

Additional troubleshooting:

```
ssh git@gitlab.foo.com git-receive-pack my-project/project.git
009a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 capabilities^{}report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet atomic ofs-delta push-options agent=git/2.22.0
0000

ssh git@gitlab.foo.com /bin/true
> GitLab: Disallowed command
```

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab

Comment: What is the output of `git remote --verbose`?

Comment: So what happens if you do `ssh <host> git-receive-pack <path-to-git-repository>` and `ssh <host> /bin/true` as suggested in this question?

Comment: @He3lixxx see above in question, all "ssh" commands seem to work but again, when I try to push, I get the above errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

This env variable was messing everything up: `GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe`
Once we did `unset GIT_SSH`, it worked.

Credit to one of the comments of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913460/523173