# fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Pa

Tags: python, git

I have recently been working with Git in [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).
But when I test the Git URL, it gives me this error:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Pa
```

The remote repository in on an internal server access through a dedicated account:

```
anAccount@ourServer:ourRepo
```

Comment: What versions of software are you using? What URL did you test? You should add enough specific detail so that someone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Basically I put debian linux on a Lego Mindstorms EV3 brick and connected it to the internet. I then made a git repo on it, and for the first day it worked but then I kept getting the error in my original post. [link to the linux distro](https://www.ev3dev.org/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fatal%3A+protocol+error%3A+bad+line+length+character

Comment: None of these resources helped me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check first if switching protocol helps:

- if the Git URL is `https://github.com/...`, switch to `ssh://git@github.com/...`
- if the Git URL is `git@github.com:...`, switch to `https://github.com/...`

For an SSH URL, try at least to:

- generate, for testing, a [PEM ssh key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309), without passphrase
- register the public key in `yourUser@yourRemoteServer:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (make sure to copy the public key content `id_rsa.pub` as *one* line in that `authorized_keys` files)
- make sure to use OpenSSH, not `Plink.exe`

That is:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%

ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" 
# Copy the %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub content to the remote server
```

Comment: It didn't fix it. I am running the git repo locally.

Comment: What is the URL of the remote repository?

Comment: OK: that is an SSH URL: Check the .profile/.bashrc file in `~robot` on the `ev3dev` server: if it prints anything (any `echo`), that would be the cause of your issue.

Comment: It turns out I am really dumb and don't know how to check the .bashrc/.profile for any errors. Can someone please help

Comment: @RussellHynes It is on the `/home/robot` folder on the `ev3dev` server: once there, do a `source .bashrc` to check if that prints anything.

Comment: It gives no ouput. I even did a fresh install  of ev3dev and it still gives the same error. It must be an issue on my windows 10 computer.

Comment: @RussellHynes On your Windows 10, do you have a `GIT_SSH` environment variable?

Comment: Yes I do have one in my environment variables. It is set to plink.exe from PuTTY

Comment: @RussellHynes Exactly! That is the problem (part of at least). Delete/unset that environment variable. Also is your private key protected by a passphrase?

Comment: @RussellHynes I have edited the answer with a step-by-step process.

Comment: It is not key protected

Comment: @RussellHynes OK, but did my answer worked? I see you have selected it, but did you test it first?

Comment: No I didn't sorry

Comment: In the middle of something

Comment: @RussellHynes No problem. The usual best practice would be to select the answer only if said answer was useful and helped you.