# Set up local git server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: git, server, raspberry-pi, git-extensions

I´m currently trying to set up a local Raspberry Pi git server and a simple git Client with GitExtension on Windows 10. However, up to this point, I configured the git server on the Raspberry pi and created the respective .git folder which contains the desired repository. I also enabled the SSH Option on the Raspberry Pi. 
Additional to that, I installed GitExtensions on Windows 10 beside Putty in order to create a SSH tunnel.

As an initial step I created an RSA key pair on the Windows 10 Client and transfered the public part of the key pair to the server (~/.ssh). Afterwards I tried to connect to the git server by building up a SSH tunnel from Windows 10 to the Raspberry git server. However, for some reasons I haven´t figured out what is going wrong. I always get the follwoing error message.

[image]

Can somebody tell me what I´m doing wrong?

Best regards

Ratbald

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing `//` after `ssh:`, and you should omit the second `:`unless you specify a port. In the end, the clone URL should read

```
ssh://myRaspi@192.168.0.51/home/git/project/meinProject.git
```

Comment: Okay, that instruction bring me to the follwoing error message:

Comment: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: myRa

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8170436/1127485, maybe that puts you on the right track.

Comment: ... in particular the GitExtension-specific answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52586001/1127485 to use OpenSSH instead of  PuTTY.

Comment: First of all I would confirm whether it is a Git Extensions issue, or git configuration, or the environment issue. Git Extensions is nothing more than a fancy UI over git cli.
Try cloning your project via git cli first - it is works, then there must be something missing in GE config. Else, you need to configure git/environment first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reach the raspberry pi via ssh command? On unices, you would type something like

```
ssh pi-user@raspberrypi.local
```

where `pi-user` is `pi` by default.

If you cannot access this, perhaps the `.ssh` directory has the wrong setup. The folder needs owner `rwx` (700) permissions, the `authorized_keys` file (which is the only that needs to exist, btw) works with owner `rw` (600).