# SSH Git error when trying to checkout - bad line length character: Exce

Tags: github, ssh

I have my repositories in 
C:\mainfolder\GitRepos\test.git on my windows PC.
I am able to login but getting this Error.
( I created the test.git using --- init bare after going to test.git folder)

```
$ git clone ssh://testuser@hostserver/mainfolder/GitRepos/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
testuser@hostserver's password:
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Exce
```

Comment: no I tried that. its giving

Comment: fatal: Too many arguments.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Remote: Error: fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Unab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170436/git-remote-error-fatal-protocol-error-bad-line-length-character-unab)