# Git: fatal: protocol error: bad line length

Tags: git

Ok, i'm getting this error and i'm not sure how I could fix it. Also I have tried looking around for help however everything I have tried has not worked.

[image]

Comment: If you’ve searched, you know the problem is on the server end. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175315/341994 But there are lots more: https://www.google.com/search?q=git+push+bad+line+length+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I still dont know who to fix this error even if i know its server sided.

Answer (score 1):

This message means that your Git client found that the remote server sent bad data.  There's a protocol format called pkt-line used by Git operations, and the message your version of Git got from the server didn't conform to that protocol format.

There are a couple possible reasons.  First, if you're on a network with a proxy or a SSL/TLS MITM device, sometimes these can corrupt data.  If so, talk to your network administrator and inform them of this.

If not, then it's likely that the server is broken and sending bad data, in which case you should contact your hosting provider, which in this case would be Bitbucket.